# Copy PowerPoint Slides in Java (preferably)

Tags: java, ms-office, powerpoint

I have a Java program in which I want to copy PowerPoint slides from one presentation into another. I have looked into the "Slides" API in Apache POI, but can't find any reference to a capability like that there.

Though the calling program will be Java, I'm open to the idea of the actual work being in another language. For example, I could run on Windows and call a COM component through [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/) or something.

How can I best achieve this? Also for clarification, I need to support both PPT and PPTX formats.

Comment: while this functionality is not currently available in POI, I've filed an enhancement request with Apache for this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53769

Comment: I just wrote code to do this using pptx4j, but pptx4j doesn't really support binary .ppt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that PowerPoint's own COM API has a built-in method that makes this quite easy: [InsertFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa832307%28office.10%29.aspx)