# Merging Powerpoint decks using Apache POI

Tags: java, powerpoint, concatenation, apache-poi

I have a folder of several ppt decks that I want to combine into one deck.  I do not see any easy way to add a slide from deck to another.  Is there a function that handles this? Is there another Java library that can do this?

Thank you!

-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll find pure java solution.

When doing some ppt reads/updates I had to move away from apache POI implementation, that seems to be quite limited.
I finally ended up with Libreoffice/OpenOffice + some java wrapper (that did the specific thing I needed)

Based on the similar/almost identical question/problem: [Copy PowerPoint Slides in Java (preferably)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959103/copy-powerpoint-slides-in-java-preferably)
and non-java based solution as the answer it probably only supports my theory of Apache POI capabilities in this area :(

Comment: uggghhhh. seems like such a simple thing to do.  but you're right, short of writing something that copies each and every element from one slide to another, there is no function that will do this.

Comment: however I believe the next step for you would be to fill a bug/feature request in Apache POI on this ( https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?list_id=88015&product=POI ), it might won't get resolved, but that's pretty much the way you can contribute to this project for improving it's capabilities :) I did also some bug reports there and I was very pleased about the progress made on these

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've done this on your suggestion: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53769  Hopefully they can make this happen! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure: I oversee the docx4j/pptx4j project**

I just wrote code to do this using pptx4j, so it is definitely do-able in Java for pptx files, using open source tools.

Comment: unfortunately, my customer has not yet advanced to office '07, so pptx files are not an option :\